# Solving for X Bit-string Flicking

Tags: theory, bitstring

I have the following problem on bit-string flicking.

Solve for X (a 5-bit string):
((10110 AND LCIRC-2 X) OR RCIRC-2 X) = 00010

I have no idea how to start

Comment: There are only 2^5 = 32 possible strings, so you can easily brute force it.

Answer (score 1):

Represent each bit as letters A-E

((10110 AND LCIRC-2 ABCDE) OR RCIRC-2 ABCDE) = 00010

((10110 AND CDEAB) OR RCIRC-2 ABCDE) = 00010

(C0EA0 OR RCIRC-2 ABCDE) = 00010

(C0EA0 OR DEABC) = 00010

We can tell that A, C, D, and E are all 0 (C OR D = 0, E OR A = 0)

Therefore, for A OR B to equal 1, B must be 1

X = 01000